# Running async computation expression in FSI

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm trying to run this code in the FSI

```
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.1\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll"

async {
    let httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
    let! response = httpClient.GetAsync("") |> Async.AwaitTask
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore
    return! response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

and I get the following error

> Error FS0193: The module/namespace 'System.Threading.Tasks' from
> compilation unit 'System.Runtime' did not contain the namespace,
> module or type 'Task`1'

However when I paste that code in a file in a project it compiles as expected.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting this error, but you should be able to reference standard .NET libraries without specifying the full path.

I tried creating an F# Script with the following and it worked perfectly fine (I'm still using F# 5, but I do not expect this would change in a new version):

```
#r @"System.Net.Http.dll"

async {
    let httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
    let! response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://tomasp.net") |> Async.AwaitTask
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() |> ignore
    return! response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I just had to add a real URL to download and `Async.RunSynchronously` to actually run the code.

Comment: Something I noted when using #r in the way you suggested is that in that way FSI shows the following message 

-->Referenced 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Net.Http.dll' and when I run the code it works!

However when I use it in the way I did in the question FSI shows a different message

--> Referenced 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.1\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll'

and when I run the code I get this error (continue in the next comment)

Comment: error FS0193: The module/namespace 'System.Threading.Tasks' from compilation unit 'System.Runtime' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'Task`1'

Do you have any idea why I'm getting that error?

Comment: I think the issue is that the libraries you were referencing were [reference libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies) which do not actually contain implementation - they are used only as API specification. (I never fully understood these, but I suspect that's what's going on!)

Comment: Thank you Tomas for you help